# Is getting the length of a Sequence a constant-time operation?

Tags: scala

I have a Sequence that I want to get the length of:

```
val x = (1 to 1000000)
x.length
```

Is this an O(1) operation? (Seems like it, from trying out a couple lines in the repl.) Why? What is a Sequence storing that makes this an O(1) operation, if it is one? (Does it just store the length of the sequence as metadata?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`(1 to 1000000)` creates a `Range` object (not the more general `Seq`).  `Range` defines `length` by calling `count`:

```
def count(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int, isInclusive: Boolean): Int = {
  // faster path for the common counting range
  if (start >= 0 && end > start && end < scala.Int.MaxValue && step == 1)
    (end - start) + ( if (isInclusive) 1 else 0 )
  else
    NumericRange.count[Long](start, end, step, isInclusive)
}
```

So, you can see that in the simple case given, a `Range` with a step size of 1, `length` is O(1) because it just subtracts `end-start` and adds one.  The `NumericRange.count` option is more complex, but still uses mathematical operations to find the value in constant time.

As for other `Seq` types:

`List` is a linked-list and does not store length information directly, so it requires traversing the entire structure and keeping track of how many elements it sees:

```
def length: Int = {
  var these = self
  var len = 0
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    len += 1
    these = these.tail
  }
  len
}
```

On the other hand, something like `Vector` stores index information, so it can return the length in constant time:

```
def length = endIndex - startIndex
```

Other `Seq` types may implement `length` in other ways.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the implementation of Seq.  Length is defined as abstract ( http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html ), so some sequences might be constant time (like arrays), some might be linear (linked lists).

Comment: ..or just "normal lists" (for immutable.Seq) :)

Comment: And some might never return, like an infinite `Stream`.

Comment: I'd think that would be a violation of the implicit contract of Seq though. I'd expect it to throw an exception on an open-ended stream (not sure what the actual behavior is).